# insert data inside defined json in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON :

```
[{"Start":{}},{"Driving route":{}},{"Lunch-Rest Break":{}},{"Break":{}},{"Waiting":{}},{"End":{}}]
```

how can I insert a data like "1/8/2014" and "1/9/2014" as a value of the key "Start" so the JSON will look like:

```
[{"Start":{"1/8/2014","1/9/2014"}},{"Driving route":{}},{"Lunch-Rest Break":{}},{"Break":{}},{"Waiting":{}},{"End":{}}]
```

Comment: parse, modify, stringify? I can  see no better option.

Comment: Your resulting JSON is invalid. Did you mean `["1/8/2014", "1/9/2014"]` for the `"Start"`?

Comment: Also, why do you have an array of one-key objects instead of a single object?

Comment: ok, this is fine too ["1/8/2014", "1/9/2014"]

Answer (score 0):

For example like this?

```
$json_string = '[{"Start":{}},{"Driving route":{}},{"Lunch-Rest Break":{}},{"Break":{}},{"Waiting":{}},{"End":{}}]'; 
$x = json_decode($json_string,true);
$x[0]['Start'] = array("1/8/2014","1/9/2014");
$return_json = json_encode($x);
print $return_json;
```